# C: Accessing functions defined in header file dynamically

Tags: c, dynamic, metaprogramming

Is there any way to access a function defined in a specific header file?

For example, in java, you can do:

```
Method m = Object.class.getMethod("foo", null);
Object result = m.invoke(null);
```

Is there any way to just pull all functions from a header, and then execute them one at a time?

Comment: no, header files are just lists of declarations.  on POSIX systems you could do a bunch of string parsing and then `dlopen` and `dlsym` a library but it wouldn't be anything close to what you need.  C doesn't have the reflection mechanisms necessary.

Comment: you probably need a building system with conditionals to perform something like that, for example `cmake`.

Comment: or use `libdl` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882771/plugin-architecture-in-c-using-libdl , it depends on what you need and when.

Comment: Looks more like a LoadLibrary/dlopen and GetProcAddress/dlsym feature that you are looking for.